# Github API /issues - pagination trouble

Tags: bash, curl, github, pagination

I am using curl from a bash command line to GET Github issues like this:

> curl -o myoutput --user "myuser:mypasswd" -G https://api.github.com/issues?filter=all

This is working fine and returns 52 open issues.

I know there are more issues, so I am also examining the headers (using -i) which provides links to the next & last pages, https://api.github.com/issues?filter=all&page=2 & https://api.github.com/issues?filter=all&page=14 respectively

However, using curl with these link URI's produces the same 52 results as before. In fact any page number I try returns the same most recent issues. I am deleting myoutput each time.

What am I missing?

Any words of wisdom on this would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I missing?

Use a [single quoted string](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashSheet#Syntax) for the URL to make sure the ampersand (e.g `&page=2`) is not interpreted as a [control operator](http://hacktux.com/bash/ampersand):

```
curl -o myoutput2 --user "user:pwd" \
'https://api.github.com/issues?filter=all&page=2'
```

*Without doing so you systematically perform a `https://api.github.com/issues?filter=all` request, which is why the output is always the same.*